# webdeploy.exe non static method requires a target

Tags: webdeploy

I am using webdeploy.exe to deploy a database instance with dbfullsql provider. The command syntax is like this:

```
msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:dbFullSql="%temp%\SQL-Database\xxxx.sql", -dest:dbFullSql="Data Source="%SQLSERVERNAME%"; database=xxxx; Persist Security Info=True; Integrated Security=true;",dropDestinationDatabase=true,transacted=false,forceScriptDatabase=true,ScriptDropsFirst=true
```

The database instance was successfully installed in target sql server instance. However i got error message like:

> Error: Non-static method requires a target
>   Error Count = 1

Any idea where the error message comes from?

Thanks